# Using multiple mail-addresses with one IMAP/SMTP account

Tags: email, smtp, outlook

I have one IMAP-account. Multiple mail-addresses on different domains are routed to this single IMAP-inbox (e.g. john@example1.com, john.doe@example2.com, doe@example3.com). Now I want to send mails via SMTP but want to choose which mail-addy is the sender.

On Mozilla Thunderbird this works perfectly using a feature called "Identities". Is MS Outlook 2003 capable of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SMTP does not care about that. The "sender" you see is basically in the payload - in the header of the message. SMTP is also used in server relay chains and unless it makes a difference in authentication, SMTP is not tied to a specific email address at all.

Comment: Yes I know that. My question is, does MS Outlook 2003 (or newer) support mutliple mail-addresses from one account?

Comment: So I vote to close - go to SuperUser if you dont ahve a professional administrator question.

Comment: according to the FAQ on serverfault, this question should be fine here, shouldn't it?

Comment: This is likely the reason it already has 3 questions to vote. What part of the FAQ do you think is relevant? This is an end user question.